# SQL RENAME TABLE command

Tags: mysql, sql, rename

I can run `RENAME TABLE student TO student_new
;`
The command is same and easy to follow.

Is there a methods to rename a lot of tables in simple command. Assume all the tables belong to the same DB name.

I don't need write a lot of code as below?

```
RENAME TABLE pre_access TO pre_new_access; 
RENAME TABLE pre_activities TO pre_new_activities;
RENAME TABLE pre_activityapplies TO pre_new_activityapplies;
RENAME TABLE pre_adminactions TO pre_new_adminactions;
RENAME TABLE pre_admincustom TO pre_new_admincustom;
RENAME TABLE pre_admingroups TO pre_new_admingroups;
RENAME TABLE pre_adminnotes TO pre_new_adminnotes;
...
```

(there are still so many tables need to be renamed)

Update: MySQL Used.

Comment: You should be able to generate that script, but that depends on the database you use...

Comment: You might want to add in the fact that you want to run this command from your SQL command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming from your comment that you use MySQL, you should be able to "select" the necessary statements from `information_schema.tables` which contains a list of your tables.

Replace `your_schema` by your schema-name and check the selected rows before executing them.

```
Select Concat( 'RENAME TABLE ', table_name, ' TO ', 'new_', table_name, ';' )
From information_schema.tables
Where table_schema = 'your_schema';
```

returns

```
RENAME TABLE c_data TO new_c_data;
RENAME TABLE c_main TO new_c_main;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always generate a simple PHP script that loops through the databases and renames them based on a REGEX expression.

Comment: Hi, I am using PHPMyAdmin. I want to use SQL command window with SQL script. Not PHP scritp. I learned a little Perl. But I know little SQL command. thanks.

Comment: Well, through phpMyAdmin alone, I don't think you're going to have much luck. If you can connect to the database with Perl, and select all databases, you can then update them to add _new at the first strpos() of a _.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what database you're using, and this is completely database dependent (some DBMSes don't even allow you to rename tables).  However, I don't know of any DBMS system off the top of my head that allows wildcards in a RENAME command so yes, you will probably have to send each command separately.

Answer (score 0):

for mysql database "test" should work:

```
echo "show tables"|mysql test|perl -ne 'if(/pre_(\w+)/){print "rename table pre_$1 to pre_new_$1;\n"}'|mysql test
```