# Rename multiple MySQL tables by inserting an underscore

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How to rename a set of MySQL tables by inserting an underscore after a keyword. The following example shows what I mean:

current names:

> keywordcache 
>   keywordfield 
>   keywordmenu 
>   etc.

expected names:

> keyword_cache 
>   keyword_field 
>   keyword_menu 
>   etc.

I use phpMyAdmin to access the data base. Renaming many tables one by one is too time-consuming so I'm looking for some automatic method.

Comment: Duplicate of [Mysql Rename Multiple tables with a pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642020/mysql-rename-multiple-tables-with-a-pattern)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with phpMyAdmin.

Go to `Structure` page of the database that contains these tables.
Check the checkboxes in front of each of the tables you want to rename. 
From `With selected` dropdown chose `Replace table prefix`.
Enter 'keyword' in `From` field and 'keyword_' in `To` field and press submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP script to get table names and then rename them in any way you want.
Those answer provide details about selecting table names:

[SQL RENAME TABLE command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645459/sql-rename-table-command)

Answer (score 0):

You can use syntax such as (and maybe generate automatically an SQL script, if copy/pastes are not easy enough):

```
RENAME TABLE keywordcache TO keyword_cache,
             keywordfield TO keyword_field,
             keywordmenu TO keyword_menu;
```

See [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html).

Comment: I've expected that maybe there is some RegEx type solution, but now i see that SQL does not support it :/ Meanwhile I will try workaround:

Comment: workaround:
 ->  export tables from phpMyAdmin to text format
 ->  paste it to Notepad++
 ->  extract only the tables names using replace option with regex support
 ->  insert "_" after the keyword
 ->  prepare SQL script using these modified names with syntax that you have mentioned
 ->  execute this script in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Regarding stefek's solution Madhura Jayaratne posted a much more elegant solutions above, rather than exporting the tables and uploading again, just use phpMyAdmin to rename the tables...less fuss or risk of problems than exporting and re-importing. Sure it would work, but there are better ways :)

Comment: Right, phpmyadmin's 'replace table prefix' feature looks to be the right tool for that. +1 for Madhura's answer :)